# CSS Applied to Only Image and Not Text

Tags: css, image

I'm kinda new to PHP and I'm really confused how things are structured. I uploaded an icon that I want to be aligned in the middle with text on the right side of the icon. I attached an image of what it looks like right now. And what I want it to look like. It's a slight difference but it's there! Help? Thanks!

[image]

```
<a href="http://footballxo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/draft.png">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3074" style="height: 26px; width: 22px;" alt="draft"
       src="http://footballxo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/draft.png"
       width="39" height="48" /></a>
<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: lighter; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #609d6f;">Draft Coverage</span>
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with PHP. You might be using PHP to generate this html, but fixing it will be a purely HTML solution.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Thanks! I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP, just HTML/CSS.  You are probably going to run into a lot of problems like these -- unfortunately, you can really only learn by experience.

What will work here is using `vertical-align: midddle` on the `<img>` and `<span>` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/xKXFj/

Comment: That did it! Sorry, I was just realized confused with WordPress's text editor. I can give you a green arrow in 7 minutes when I'm allowed too. Thanks again!